# How to make a subroutine that adds 2 numbers?

Tags: assembly, subroutine

I want to make a subroutine that adds 2 numbers and puts the answer back on the stack. I'm using ZEP2 simulator.

This is my code so far. I searched on google for some useful information.

```
 ##  

stack equ  0x0010

begin  

load sp, stack

          push 5

          push 3

          jsr sadd

          halt 

 sadd     pop R1

          pop R2

          add R1, R2

          push R1 

          ret             

 ##
```

I expect output of 8 on the stack by adding 5 and 3.

Comment: What doesn't work? Bad result? Error message?

Comment: I don't know if I'm doing it right. I don't get any error messages. I can see that there is a 8 in the memory. I just want to know if it is good what I'm doing.

Comment: I posted the rest of the code. I'm trying to calculate 5 × 3 + 4/2 − 1 using subroutines. It is not working. The error I'm getting is unknown operation 0x00. processor halted

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> pop R1
> pop R2
> add R1, R2
> push R1 
> ret
> ```

Your subroutine forgets that the `JSR` instruction has placed a return address on the stack! The `POP R1` instruction does not retrieve a useful operand. It pops the return address instead.
Moreover the `RET` instruction will no longer return to below the `JSR` instruction.

Next code will fetch the correct values from the stack:

```
load R2, SP
inc  R2
load R1, (R2)   ; This is the 3 in your example
inc  R2
add  R1, (R2)   ; This adds the 5 in your example
ret
```

> and puts the answer back on the stack.

This means replacing **2** values above the pushed return address by **1** value. Next is one way of doing this:

```
store R1, (R2)  ; Replace input value 5 by the sum 8
pop   R1        ; Pop the return address
pop   R2        ; Remove the input value 3
push  R1        ; Put the return address back
ret             ; ... so RET can use it correctly
```